# ng5-slider does not update form control value when dragging

Tags: angular

I am dealing with an issue. I have tested the reactive form module demo in my angular application (see at https://angular-slider.github.io/ng5-slider/demos). Everything works fine, except that the form control value does not update when dragging as it is on the demo example. I have to release the slider pointer to make the form control value updated.

I am currently working with this angular conf :

> "dependencies": { "@angular/animations": "~7.0.0", "@angular/common":
>   "~7.0.0", "@angular/compiler": "~7.0.0", "@angular/core": "~7.0.0",
>   "@angular/forms": "~7.0.0", "@angular/http": "~7.0.0",
>   "@angular/platform-browser": "~7.0.0",
>   "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~7.0.0", "@angular/router":
>   "~7.0.0", "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
>   "angular2-loaders-css": "^2.0.1", "angular2-moment": "^1.9.0",
>   "bootstrap": "^4.1.3", "core-js": "^2.5.4", "ng5-slider": "^1.1.13",
>   "ngx-cookie-service": "^2.0.0", "rxjs": "~6.3.3", "zone.js": "~0.8.26"
>   },

Here is the surcout.component.html file  :

```
      <form [formGroup]="repartitionRemplacementsForm">
          <div class="row mb-3 pl-5 pr-5 align-items-baseline d-flex" *ngFor="let remplacement of remplacements">
            <div class="col-3">
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col mx-auto">
                  <img class="img-csp surcout-repartition" [src]='remplacement.imgCsp'>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col mx-auto">
                  <span class="csp-poste">{{remplacement.csp}}</span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-9 text-center">
              <div class="row mb-0 solution-header indicateurs">
                <div class="col-6 title cdd"><p>{{repartitionRemplacementsForm.controls[remplacement.csp].value}}%</p></div>
                <div class="col-6 interim-sous-traitance title"><p>{{100-repartitionRemplacementsForm.controls[remplacement.csp].value}}%</p></div>
              </div>
              <div class="row">
                <div class="col">
                  <ng5-slider [options]="options" [formControlName]="remplacement.csp" class="simple-slider"></ng5-slider>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
```

here is how I init options of the slider in surcout.component.ts :

```
options: Options = {
floor: 0,
ceil: 100,
step: 5,
hideLimitLabels: true,
hidePointerLabels: true,
showSelectionBarFromValue: -10};
```

If anyone can test it an say me if it works, it could be so nice !

Thanks

Comment: please share your code what you have done until

Comment: I added the html and the variable i used for the slider. Don't hesitate to ask if you need more info ;)

Comment: /* ng5-slider update */
const newOptions: Options = Object.assign({}, this.options);
this.options = newOptions;